# How to update the webview contents?

Tags: android, html, webview

I have edited the HTML from a website (I am experimenting so I have been using bbc.co.uk) and have placed it in the assets folder, from there I have loaded the page using .loadurl() onto my webview however, the contents do not update with the website(Therfore content gets outdated) how can I proceed to make the contents of my webview to be up to date with the original website?

Comment: after wt time data get outdated. n wt ur doing asset folder ?

Comment: @sush outdated as in it doesn't update its contents whenever the website adds anything new etc. and i placed the html in the assests folder to edit its layout (like i said i am experimenting and not very experienced with webview, the layout is changed as i wanted it to but the contents do not update)